# SQL Server Update Join Two Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm having a bit of trouble getting MSSQL to cooperate with my intentions.

Examine the following...

Duplicates

```
UseId |   Use
-------------
2254  | Primary
2255  | Primary
2256  | Primary
2257  | Intersection
2258  | Monitor
2259  | Primary
2260  | Intersection
2261  | Primary
2264  | Monitor
2269  | Secondary
```

Uniques

```
UseID |   Use
--------------
2252  | Intersection
2253  | Monitor
2251  | Primary
2262  | Secondary
```

Many to Many Table

```
ID   | FKey | UseId
-------------------
1    |  1   | 2251
2    |  1   | 2252
3    |  2   | 2253
4    |  2   | 2262
5    |  3   | 2254
6    |  3   | 2257
7    |  3   | 2258
8    |  4   | 2255
9    |  4   | 2260
10   |  5   | 2259
11   |  5   | 2269
```

I want to run an update query on the "Many to Many" table that will match the use column on the duplicates and uniques, and then replace and "Duplicate" UseIds in the many to many table with their matching unique UseId...

The resulting good data would look like this....

Good Many to Many Table...

```
ID   | FKey | UseId
-------------------
1    |  1   | 2251
2    |  1   | 2252
3    |  2   | 2253
4    |  2   | 2262
5    |  3   | 2251
6    |  3   | 2252
7    |  3   | 2253
8    |  4   | 2251
9    |  4   | 2262
10   |  5   | 2251
11   |  5   | 2262
```

Any help is appreciated

---

In response to one of the posted answers... I'm having some difficulties. It doesn't seem to be working.

The update command is changing records 1-4 in the Many to Many table (even though they are good)... and not changing any of the other records.

This script provides an example of the problem.

```
CREATE TABLE Uniques
(
    UseID INT,
    [Use] VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO Uniques (UseID, [Use]) VALUES (2254, 'Primary')
INSERT INTO Uniques (UseID, [Use]) VALUES (2255, 'Primary')
INSERT INTO Uniques (UseID, [Use]) VALUES (2256, 'Primary')
INSERT INTO Uniques (UseID, [Use]) VALUES (2257, 'Intersection')
INSERT INTO Uniques (UseID, [Use]) VALUES (2258, 'Monitor')
INSERT INTO Uniques (UseID, [Use]) VALUES (2259, 'Primary')
INSERT INTO Uniques (UseID, [Use]) VALUES (2260, 'Intersection')
INSERT INTO Uniques (UseID, [Use]) VALUES (2261, 'Primary')
INSERT INTO Uniques (UseID, [Use]) VALUES (2264, 'Monitor')
INSERT INTO Uniques (UseID, [Use]) VALUES (2269, 'Secondary')

CREATE TABLE Duplicates
(
    UseID INT,
    [Use] VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO Duplicates (UseID, [Use]) VALUES (2252, 'Intersection')
INSERT INTO Duplicates (UseID, [Use]) VALUES (2253, 'Monitor')
INSERT INTO Duplicates (UseID, [Use]) VALUES (2251, 'Primary')
INSERT INTO Duplicates (UseID, [Use]) VALUES (2262, 'Secondary')

CREATE TABLE ManyToMany
(
    Id INT,
    FKey INT,
    UseId INT
)

INSERT INTO ManyToMany (Id, FKey, UseId) VALUES (1, 1, 2251)
INSERT INTO ManyToMany (Id, FKey, UseId) VALUES (2, 1, 2252)
INSERT INTO ManyToMany (Id, FKey, UseId) VALUES (3, 2, 2253)
INSERT INTO ManyToMany (Id, FKey, UseId) VALUES (4, 2, 2262)
INSERT INTO ManyToMany (Id, FKey, UseId) VALUES (5, 3, 2254)
INSERT INTO ManyToMany (Id, FKey, UseId) VALUES (6, 3, 2257)
INSERT INTO ManyToMany (Id, FKey, UseId) VALUES (7, 3, 2258)
INSERT INTO ManyToMany (Id, FKey, UseId) VALUES (8, 4, 2255)
INSERT INTO ManyToMany (Id, FKey, UseId) VALUES (9, 4, 2260)
INSERT INTO ManyToMany (Id, FKey, UseId) VALUES (10, 5, 2259)
INSERT INTO ManyToMany (Id, FKey, UseId) VALUES (11, 5, 2269)

SELECT * FROM Uniques
SELECT * FROM Duplicates
SELECT * FROM ManyToMany

UPDATE  m
SET     m.UseId = u.UseId
FROM    ManyToMany m
        JOIN Duplicates d ON m.UseId = d.UseId
        JOIN Uniques u ON d.[Use] = u.[Use];

SELECT * FROM ManyToMany

DROP TABLE Uniques
DROP TABLE Duplicates
DROP TABLE ManyToMany
```

Comment: this is confusing because the data is not complete. Where are you getting the ID and FKey from? How are you creating your 'Many to Many' table right now?

Comment: One wonders how you got into this mess in the first place, but Kevin Suchlicki's answer looks correct.

Comment: In the many to many table, ID is a an INT IDENTITY field. The foreign key just points at another table that is irrelevant (probably should have left it out of the example).

Comment: For inquiring minds, my task is to read in an XML file, and parse it into some tables. The result is a lot duplicate data because of the design of the XML file. I need to delete all the duplicate records from one table, but it has a relationship to the many to many table... so the "unique" and "duplicate" datasets above are the result of queries in the main table... So I need to update all the records in the "many to many" table with their "unique" counterparts before I delete the original duplicate records.... if that makes sense...

Comment: Kevin's answer is correct, but you mis-named your tables. Change the table `Uniques` to `Duplicates` and `Duplicates` to `Uniques` and his answer will yield the correct results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE  m
SET     m.UseId = u.UseId
FROM    ManyToMany m
        JOIN Duplicates d ON m.UseId = d.UseId
        JOIN Uniques u ON d.[Use] = u.[Use];
```

Comment: This answer is correct, but you (imdandman) mis-named your tables in your posted sample. Change the table `Uniques` to `Duplicates` and `Duplicates` to `Uniques` and this answer will yield the correct results.

Comment: @mdisibio Thanks for looking at this

Comment: Thank you for the help! Sorry for my confusion.